# SolidWorks to URDF Error

Tags: ros2, urdf, ubuntu, solidworks, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the following error when I try to preview and export my CAD to URDF:

"The process cannot access the file '_________' because it is being used by another process."

Anyone have an idea as to how I can fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285870/solidworks-to-urdf-error/) by [Trexo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34221/trexo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-03-20**:
@Trexo may u more clarify the question with screenshot or any other form that show us error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Error generating link STL](https://bitbucket.org/brawner/sw2urdf/issues/34/error-generating-link-stl) seems to be your issue.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1